# What does "unsupported" in package version mean?

Tags: python, python-packaging

I'm setting up my requirements.txt, and I see that in my development environment I have "pyodbc==4.0.0-unsupported".

```
> pip show pyodbc

Name: pyodbc
Version: 4.0.0-unsupported
Summary: DB API Module for ODBC
Home-page: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc
Author: None
Author-email: None
License: MIT
Location: /local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-02ceb239-f645-45e1-ad42-93017835482c/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: 
Required-by:
```

What does it mean?

I'm using Python 3.7

Isn't it weird that pip installs an old version ([2016](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/releases/tag/4.0.0)) of this package?

Comment: can you install the latest one `pip install -U pyodbc`

Comment: In short it output: `Successfully uninstalled pyodbc-4.0.0-unsupported, Successfully installed pyodbc-4.0.32`

Comment: Now pip show would be giving the latest one

Comment: Yes indeed, but how come pip installed pyodbc then?

Comment: You mean the unsupported version that I dont know!

Comment: If this helps you should I add a answer of it so that you can accept it?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'd like the explanation of the "unsupported" bit, where it comes from and what does it mean here.

Comment: can you paste the history of commands that you fired. I dont know how you installed the older version cause for my case its working fine. And maybe you have explicitly installed the unsupported version by `pip install pyodbc==4.0.0` If you are having a doubt then just uninstall the current library and reinstall it again it will install the latest version only

Comment: I'm using Databricks with the runtime 7.3 ML LTS, that comes with pyodbc pre-installed. When I retrieve the logs of the init script for my cluster this is what I see: `Requirement already satisfied: pyodbc in /databricks/conda/envs/databricks-ml/lib/python3.7/site-packages (4.0.0-unsupported)`

Comment: pip install -U pyodbc does the trick